# Isolated scope within directive controller bindings

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

## The problem

### Given the following directive

```
angular.module('sandbox.directive.controllers', [])
.directive('simpleDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {user: '='},
    controller: 'simpleController',
    templateUrl: 'directive-controllers/templates/simpleDirective.html'
  };
})
.controller('simpleController', function($scope, $element) {
  $scope.title = "Hello from the controller!";
});
```

### Why does this test fail?

```
it('should allow us update when we change the title', function() {
  element.scope().title = "Marco Polo!";
  element.scope().$digest();
  expect(element.html()).toContain('Marco Polo!');
});
```

My full implementation can be [seen here](https://github.com/karlbright/angularjs-sandbox/blob/master/src/directive-controllers/directive-controllers.js) and the tests [here](https://github.com/karlbright/angularjs-sandbox/blob/master/src/directive-controllers/test/directive-controllers.test.js).

## My understanding

I am currently trying to get a better understanding of scope within directives. I have written a few tests which illustrate most of the use cases quite clearly. However I am having issues with how a directives controller relates to the isolated scope.

My understanding was that the scope accessible within the controller is a reference to the scopes directive.

## Please help

I understand the issue with two-way bindings on primitives, however this is within the isolated scope and not the parent scope. Any help to get a better understanding of this would be appreciated.

Comment: what happens if your replace element.scope() by $rootScope in your test ?

Comment: I am not user you can access the isolated scope with element.scope()

Comment: @laurent That would be bad practice as you would be accessing the scope outside of the directive. If multiple directives were on the page this would affect the scope within the other directives.

The isolated scope can be access when it using a two-way binding assigned with the scope attribute of a directive (see other tests which all pass). However accessing an attribute here that is assigned via the controller does not.

The same issue occurs when assigning a title via the link function(bad practice).

Comment: Sure, but then why do you want in your test to manually change isolated scope value of title if it is not exposed to the outside world ? I would rather test expect(element.html()).toContain("Hello from the controller!"); Because making manual change and test the result in the markup for me is equivalent to test internal implementation details. If you expose on your controller a method changeTitle('new value') then it makes sense to check if it has the expected effect on the markup

Comment: The test is to illustrate how the scope is defined. Although the test may not illustrate that a controller is able to update the isolated scope of the directive. I am still interested as to what is happening internally here to cause this test to fail when the controller assigns the scope property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be an element.isolateScope() property.

The two-way binding assigned for a user was passing as the parent scope was returned from element.scope(), therefore when user was changed the binding was in affect and the value was updated within the isolated scope.

The element.isolateScope() returns the scope when it is isolated(as it is in this case) and allows me to update this value correctly.

The element.scope() and element.isolateScope() functions are explained [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).